# Can I use 2 iPhones as walkie talkie? (without internet!)

Tags: iphone, wifi, call, voip

I want to use 2 (or more) iPhones as walkie talkie (i.e. they talk each other without needing internet/voice call).

Of course this should work with wifi, because it doesn't make much sense a to have bluetooth or usb connection for this application...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several apps that will do this in the iTunes Store. The search to use is "[walkie talkie](http://ax.search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?entity=software&media=software&page=1&restrict=true&startIndex=0&term=walkie+talkie)". I recommend you look first at [Walkie-Talkie - iOS](http://appshopper.com/utilities/walkie-talkie-2).

Comment: The point here is someone doing [that search](http://appshopper.com/search/?search=walkie-talkie) and recommending a single good app that will do the job.

Comment: This app http://appshopper.com/utilities/walkie-talkie-2 looks good. Please someone post this as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 4):

There's an app for that™.

[**WiChat**](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wichat-bonjour-chat-client/id408197222?mt=8) will allow you to chat with the [*Bonjour*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29) protocol, that is, chatting with people on the local network without connecting to an external server.

Comment: Nice, but this is for IM, not actual voice talk.