# App and hardware to use phone as a one way ‘walkie talkie’

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth, voice

I am looking for an app and a battery power device so I can use my phone as a audio transmitter to the device. The device will be plugged into some noise cancelling headphones for my child.
My child has audio processing difficulty and I am experimenting with different options to support her at home. I am hoping I can use my phone as a transmitter to send audio messages directly to the receiver plugged into her headphones so she can hear messages loud and clear around the house when required. 
Has anyone seen anything like this or similar? Thanks in advance

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14875/can-i-use-2-iphones-as-walkie-talkie-without-internet?rq=1

Comment: @ankiiiiiii How does the link you shared help? OP is clearly looking for a hardware accessory which can plug into a headphone and receive audio messages by some means (such as over an Internet connection)

Comment: @NimeshNeema 1. I sometimes link questions which are even a bit related and there is a chance that OP skips searching the site or App Store etc. It always doesn't mean that they are dupes or I am in any intent trying to get someone to flag them. 2. If the linked apps answer the query ( plugging the headphones into another iphone, if possible and available, which I find inappropriate to ask in comments.),  it is a win-win situation. If not, I don't mind then either, feel free to flag as obsolete/ irrelevant.

Comment: @NimeshNeemaI understand Sam has found the noise canceling headphone his daughter needs.

Comment: @Sam my reading of your question is that you are looking for a walkie-talkie app. https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/best-walkie-talkie-app/  or https://apps.apple.com/us/app/zello-walkie-talkie/id508231856

Comment: @Sam In order to answer your question in more detail we need to know more about the "battery power device".  One such device would be another iPhone. You can get an iPhone se or iPhone 5s for a reasonable price.  If the iphone is too old, you will not be able to get modern software for it.

Comment: I think we were assuming the other device was another iPhone.